# Comparing two CSV files using lists and dictionaries

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have two CSV files, the first with 3 columns and numerous rows and the second with 4 columns and numerous rows, I am trying to retrieve data from the 1st file based on the RemoveDes list (In code), "RemovedDes" is a filtered version of File 2, which has filtered out rows of data where the first letter is 'E' in the Destination column of File 2. Not all data from File 1 is going to be used, only data which corresponds to the RemoveDes hence why I need to compare the two.

How can I print out only the relevant data from file 1?

I know it's probably very easy to do but I am new to this, any assistance is much appreciated, cheers.

(for further clarification; I'm after the Eastings and Northings in File 1 but need to use "RemovedDes" (which filtered out unnecessary information in File2) to match the data in the two files)

```
File 1 Sample Data (many more rows):
Destination Easting Northing
    D4 .      102019 . 1018347
    D2 .      102385 . 2048908

File 2 Sample Data (many more rows):
Legend Destination Distance Width
 10       D4 .        67 .     87
 18       E2 .        32 .     44
```

Note that E2 is filtered out as it starts with E.. See code bellow for clarification.

```
Legend Destination Distance Width

    1stFile = open(file2.csv, 'r')
    FILE1 = 1stFile.readlines()
    print(FILE1)

  list_dictionary = []
    2ndFile = open(file2.csv, 'r') 
    FILE2 = 2ndFile.readlines()
    print(FILE2)
    for line in FILE2:
        values = line.split(',')
        Legend = values[0]
        Destination = values[1]
        Distance = values[2]
        Width = values[3]

        diction_list['LEG'] = Legend
        diction_list['DEST'] = Destination
        diction_list['DIST'] = Distance
        diction_list['WID'] = Width

        list_dictionary.append(the_dictionary)

    RemovedDes = [] 
    for line_dict in list_dictionary:
        if not li_dict['DEST'].startswith('E'): #Filters out rows of data which starts with the letter E in File 2.
            RemovedDes.append(li_dict)

    print(RemovedDes)
```

Comment: Can you provide some data samples of your csv files?

Comment: Within the data samples, can you also tell us what the expected output should be?

Comment: Sample data was added.

Comment: I'm not too sure what you mean dave, I think I over explained. Basically File 2 has the same data as File 1 does however both files have more data than necessary. File 2 was filtered to remove any unnecessary data and I now want to use the filtered version to retrieve the eastings and northings based on the column destination which both files have.

Comment: Am I right in assuming you have fewer rows in File 2 since unnecessary rows have been filtered out and now you want to retrieve the corresponding rows from file 1 (those who share the same values for `Destination`)?

Comment: Yep, exactly what I need.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the clarification in the comments, I suggest the following approach:

1. use a `pandas.DataFrame` as your data structure of choice
2. perform a join of your lists

The following code will create a `pandas` data frame `data` with all entries of `file2`, extended by their respective entries in the columns `Easting` and `Northing` of `file1`

```
import pandas as pd

file1 = pd.read_csv('file1.csv')
file2 = pd.read_csv('file2.csv')

data = pd.merge(file2, file1, how = 'left', on = 'Destination')
```

Note: this assumes that `Destination` has unique values across the board and that both .csv-Files come with a header line.

Comment: Should you wish to use only the columns from `file1`, you can add the line `data1 = data[['Destination', 'Easting', 'Northing']]` to my above code snippet to create a data frame with only the rows from `file2` and the columns from `file1` (though there are more efficient ways to achieve that result, so if that is what you need let me know and I'll write up a detailed approach).